# Why android emulator looks different after the last update?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Why after the last update android emulator looks different from the previous look? Is there a way to bring it back?

[**Current look**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBrfz.png)

[**Previous look**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I617.png)

All checks are made on API 30.

Comment: What specifically concerns you about the look?

Comment: @CommonsWare At a glance widget has disappeared, many pixel-like things are lost aswell.

Comment: does this change actually make a difference to prevent you from getting work done ? i believe that was the intent behind the initial question

Comment: @a_local_nobody Even if it doesn't, it would be nice to know actual reason behind such things. That's the intent for me.